# Quaternion Translation

Tags: 3d, rotation, directx11, quaternion

I am writing a small game and I need some help with my quaternions.

If I have an object at rotation A (quaternion)

And I need it to be at rotation B (quaternion) in 10 steps how would I work out the step change?

For normal vectors I would do C = (B - A) / 10
And then each step simply add C to my position to move from A to B in 10 steps.
I don't believe this would work for quaternions so how do I do this?

Also there would be an infinite number of routes that could be taken to get from A to B, so I would like to calculate this for the shortest route.

I did find this http://wasted.nz/posts.php?topic=82629
But if this is correct then how do you apply the difference to the current rotation? and could this difference be divided by 10 to get the step difference?

If it helps I am using C++, DirectX 11 and Bullet Physics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this operation

```
q' = q.inverseQuaternion() * q2
```

q' is a quaternion holding the rotation from q2 to q1.

For the stepping part, you should search for **LERP** or **SLERP**

Comment: [DirectXMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath) implements ``XMQuaternionSlerp``, but note that for small angles ``XMVectorLerp`` is a lot faster.

Comment: @Paul Spain nice to know. Please mark the answer as accepted if it was the right solution for your question :)

Comment: I wanted to test it some more before ticking this as the answer. All works perfectly.

Comment: Ok. I'm glad it helped